# How to get access to the redux store when using ReactDOM.render to the rendering element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've built a tab component which renders 8 tab items. Each tab is associated to a component which does very expensive operations. Having all 8 components rendering on component mount impacts the performance heavily.

To optimise the performance, instead of rendering all 8 components all at once, I've mapped through my tabs array and rendered an empty div placeholder which will lazily load the component to the empty div for the first time on each tab click. I have got this successfully working however after each tab component mounts I do not have access to the redux store.

Can someone please explain on why and advise on how I can solve this?

Thanks

sample code

```
const handleTabClick = tabIndex => event => {
   setSelectedTab(tabIndex);
   renderContentBlock(tabIndex);
};

const renderContentBlock = tabIndex => {
  const updatedTabs = [...tabs];

  // no need to rerender content block if already rendered
  if (updatedTabs[tabIndex].rendered) return;

  updatedTabs[tabIndex].rendered = true;

  ReactDOM.render(
    <LazyLoad component={updatedTabs[tabIndex].component} />,
    document.getElementById(updatedTabs[tabIndex].name)
  );

  setTabs(updatedTabs);
};
```

---

```
{
  tabs.map((tab, index) => (
    <div
        key={index}
        onClick={handleTabClick(index)}
    >
      {tab.name}
    </div>

  ))
}

{ 
  tabs.map((tab, index) => (
   <div
     key={index}
     id={tab.name}
     ref={el => (expandedContentBlockRef.current[index] = el)}
   /></div>
  ))
}
```

Comment: reasons for using `ReactDOM.render()` ?

Comment: @xadm,  is there another way on rendering a component to it's associated div?

Comment: just render tabs row and a row of contents; `tabs.map((tab, index) => <Tab active={index==selected} tab={tab}/>` ... active changes style ... the same for `<TabContent />` but renders null for not selected   - result: only one rendered

Answer (score 2):

When you use `ReactDOM.render()` to render a component to a DOM node outside of the React tree, it's not part of the original tree, and doesn't have access to the context. This means that it can't be connected to the redux store, which is managed via the context.

A possible solution would be to use [`ReactDOM.createPortal()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#createportal), which maintains the connection to the tree, while rendering the content to a different DOM node:

```
ReactDOM.createPortal(
  <LazyLoad component={updatedTabs[tabIndex].component} />,
  document.getElementById(updatedTabs[tabIndex].name)
);
```

However, your main concern is to lazy load/render a tab. Since only a single tab's content can be displayed, you don't actually need to render all of them at once. In addition, react has a built in code [splitting/lazy loading](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) mechanism that you might leverage for your case.

Example (not tested):

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy, useState, useCallback } from 'react';

const tabs = [{ title: 'TabA', path: 'tabAFilePath' }, { title: 'TabB', path: 'tabBFilePath' }, ...] // an array of paths to Component's files in your code
  .map(o => ({ ...o, Page: lazy(() => import(o.path) }))

const Tab = ({ tab, setTab }) => {
  const setCurrentTab = useCallback(() => setTab(tab), [tab]);

  return (
    <div onClick={setCurrentTab}>{tab.title}</div>
  );
};

const Tabs = () => {
  const [current, setTab] = useState(tabs[0]);

  const { Page } = current;

  return (
    <div>{tabs.map(tab => <Tab tab={tab} setTab={setTab} />)}</div>

    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Page />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi @Ori, Thank you for your detailed answer. I now have a better understanding of the React tree. One question though, I will need to animate each div (which wraps each rendered component). 

I will need to calculate and update the inline style css transform values (yAxis) for all placeholder divs every time you click on a tab. This will allow me to either transition the div placeholders from top to bottom or bottom to top. 

With your approach, there is only going to be one tab component displayed at a time. How would I bake this in with your approach ? 

Happy to post some sample code?

Comment: Don't animate everything by hand, use a library like [React Transition Group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/switch-transition) to it for you. There are many libraries out there, so you might want to do a bit of research.